# Spring Interceptor: how to populate model in preHandle method?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

So basically question listed in title. Is there a way to populate `org.springframework.ui.Model` in `preHandle` method ?

```
public class SomeInterceptor extends HandlerInterceptorAdapter {
    @Override
    public boolean preHandle(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, Object handler) throws Exception {
        // need to populate Model here
        return true;
    }
}
```

Comment: No because there is no model yet...

Comment: @M.Deinum So Model created at the time controller is executed ? may you procuce a link ? is there other way to provide an attribute to model ?

Comment: You can use `setAttribute()` method of `HttpServletRequest` to pass data to controller. Then in controller you would use `getAttribute()` of `HttpServletRequest` to get this data and put it into model.

Comment: Or use `@ControllerAdvice` in combination with `@ModelAttribute`